# How to add values from parents in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I read the cost of processes from a CSV file as

```
Process    Parent    Cost    Total_Cost
1                    5       5
2                    11      11
3          2         2       13 (2+11)
4          3         4       17 (4+2+11)
5          1         3       8 (3+5)
```

The fourth column is not in the CSV file, and I need to calculate it by adding the cost of parents.

I read the columns into a multidimensional array as

```
Array (
...
[3] => Array ('Parent' => 2, 'Cost' => 2),
[4] => Array ('Parent' => 3, 'Cost' => 4),
...
);
```

I understand that I should iterate the array to get the parent cost and add it to the process cost. But this is not the right array structure for fetching the cost of parents.

Can you give me a hint about what should be my array structure?

Comment: personally I'd build the array with the parent ID = array key, then subarray of children with their costs in there, then just array_sum recursively on that array where id = parent

Comment: @treyBake How would you handle multi-level parents (parent of a parent)?

Comment: How many levels can the parent go to?

Comment: @treyBake practically, not many, around 5, but it is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is not to have to calculate the timings at the end, but to do it whilst reading the file.  Each time you read a line build up the data and then store this along with a total_cost in an array indexed by the process number.  Then when you find a line with a parent - lookup the parent line and add the total_cost from the parent to the new cost.

```
$fileName = "a.csv";
$timings = [];
$fh = fopen( $fileName, "r" );
// Read the header
$headers = fgetcsv($fh);
while ( $process = fgetcsv($fh) )   {
    // Add keys
    $newTimings = array_combine($headers, $process);
    $totalCost = $process[2];
    if ( !empty($process[1]) )  {
        $totalCost += $timings[$process[1]]["Total_Cost"] ?? 0;
    }
    $newTimings["Total_Cost"] = $totalCost;
    $timings[$process[0]] = $newTimings;
}
print_r($timings);
```

This generates (with the test data from the question)...

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Process] => 1
            [Parent] => 
            [Cost] => 5
            [Total_Cost] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Process] => 2
            [Parent] => 
            [Cost] => 11
            [Total_Cost] => 11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Process] => 3
            [Parent] => 2
            [Cost] => 2
            [Total_Cost] => 13
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Process] => 4
            [Parent] => 3
            [Cost] => 4
            [Total_Cost] => 17
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Process] => 5
            [Parent] => 1
            [Cost] => 3
            [Total_Cost] => 8
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easiest to just use a simple recursive function to calculate the cost.

```
function cost_recursive($process, $process_array) {
  if(empty($process_array[$process]['Parent']))
    return $process_array[$process]['Cost'];
  return $process_array[$process]['Cost'] + cost_recursive($process_array[$process]['Parent'], $process_array);
}
```